# Excel, Create Table with existing horizontal data headers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a table to put a slicer in my data. But my data headers are not A1, B1, C1, they are A1, A2, A3.

Is there a way to create a table on this data without doing any data transformation?

Sample Data :

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+
|   Date   |  11/04/2017  |  12/04/2017  |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| stack    | -8578944.742 | -30182092.86 |
| overflow | -435729.7299 | -442450.9061 |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to be filter out dates in this table.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is a feature built-in to Excel. Is there a technical limitation keeping you from transposing the table?

Comment: @JaredT , kind of :( .. I want to make it as little steps as possible..

Comment: Ctrl-A to select all, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, tap control, tap T. If this is a very common task it would be trivial to create a macro

Comment: @JaredT I have many data sets this way though, so its kind of tedious to do it to each one. Maybe ill figure something out..

Comment: Yes short of a solution unknown to me I would explore the idea of a small Python script that watches a directory for new files/updates and transposes your data as necessary.

Comment: No it's not possible even if you transform the Data Table, ultimately Excel uses the the column headings as Table Header!!